# Javascript issue with functions not changing the inputs

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to use a function to change an input to what is set within the parameters.  The checks work fine in determining if the input is correct, but the don't change the original inputs.  I feel like it is something small I am missing, is anyone able to help?
Here is my code:

```
var x = prompt("enter number");
var y = prompt("enter number");

function isThisRowNumberCorrect(number1){
if (isNaN(number1) === true){
    alert("Please choose a row number between 0 and 5!");
    number1 = prompt("Please choose a row number between 0 and 5.")-'';
}
if (number1 > 5){
    alert("Please choose a row number between 0 and 5!");
    number1 = prompt("Please choose a row number between 0 and 5.")-'';
}
if (number1 < 0){
    alert("Please choose a row number between 0 and 5!");
    number1 = prompt("Please choose a row number between 0 and 5.")-'';
}
number1 = number1;
}

function isThisColumnNumberCorrect(number2){
if (isNaN(number2) === true){
    alert("Please choose a column number between 0 and 5!");
    number2 = prompt("Please choose a column number between 0 and 5.")-'';
}
if (number2 > 5){
    alert("Please choose a column number between 0 and 5!");
    number2 = prompt("Please choose a column number between 0 and 5.")-'';
}
if (number2 < 0){
    alert("Please choose a column number between 0 and 5!");
    number2 = prompt("Please choose a column number between 0 and 5.")-'';
}

number2 = number2;
}
isThisRowNumberCorrect(x);
isThisColumnNumberCorrect(y);

console.log(x + "" + y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters of the two functions are primitive type. When passed into the function, JavaScript engine will create a new copy of the primitive parameters. So setting the value inside the function `number2 = number2;` will not change the value outside.

You need to return the new value from the function `isThisRowNumberCorrect`:

```
return number1;
```

And call the function like:

```
x = isThisRowNumberCorrect(x);
```

Comment: See, I knew it was something simple, this is for a much much larger game code and its been bugging me the last few hours.  Thank you

Comment: @Havamere My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the result of the prompt to your variable within your functions which then possibly miss conditions. Also, your functions don't return anything. They just create a global variables. Your  editor should have a mild warning for assigning the argument to a variable with the same name. Although I advise against using `prompt` and `alert` you may want your code to look something like:

```
function promptRowExample(){
  var p = prompt('Please Choose a Row Between 0 and 5.');
  if(p < 0 || p > 5 || isNaN(p)){
    return promptRowExample();
  }
  return 'The Number '+p+' is a Valid Number!';
}
console.log(promptRowExample());
```